# SAS : Convert dollar amount to decimal packed amount

Tags: sql, sas

I could convert the decimal packed amounts to Numeric amounts but unable to do this reversely.

```
data HAVE;
amount = '00000258Q';output;
amount = '000000000';output;
amount = '00002488M';output;
amount = '00002126P';output;
amount = '000007{ ';output;
run;

data WANT;
set HAVE;
amount_dollar = input(cats(amount),zdv10.);
run;
```

That is -

```
data HAVE;
amount_dollar = -2588;output;
amount_dollar = .;output;
amount_dollar = -24884;output;
amount_dollar = -21267;output;
amount_dollar = 70;output;
run;
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last value is is shorter than the others and that is why you needed to add the `cats()` function (or a `trim()` or `strip()` function) to remove the trailing blanks from what you pass to the `ZDV.` informat.  Actually your other values are actually only 9 characters long and not 10.  Your all zero value is going to get translated to missing by the `ZDV.` informat, but will be converted to zero by the `ZD.` informat since it doesn't mind that the nibble with the sign is 0.

Use the `ZD.` format to generate zoned decimal strings, but note that it will add the leading zeros to the last value and sign nibble to the all zero value.

```
data test;
  input original $9. ;
  num=input(original,zd9.);
  numv=input(original,zdv9.);
  numt=input(trim(original),zd9.);
  string=put(numt,zd9.);
  same = string=original;
cards;
00000258Q
000000000
00002488M
00002126P
000007{
;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

SAS didn't make a ZDV format, as it wouldn't make sense, but you still have the ZD format:

```
data want;
  set have;
  amount = put(amount_dollar,zd10.);
run;
```

If it matters, this is not precisely a packed decimal, but a zoned decimal (packed decimal is, unsurprisingly, PDw.d, among others).